# Download .pdf file from web with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I download .pdf file from web with puppeteer? The site that I am using need cookies that must be imported before accessing.

I have already tried this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
  await page.setCookie({
    "domain": "africau.edu",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "test",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "value": "testvalue",
    "id": 1
});
  await page.pdf({ path: 'sample.pdf', format: 'A4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Error that I get:

```
C:\Users\Khaniini\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:194
                    ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                      ^

Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
    at navigate (C:\Users\Khaniini\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:194:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (C:\Users\Khaniini\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:170:21)
    at async Frame.goto (C:\Users\Khaniini\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:589:16)
    at async Page.goto (C:\Users\Khaniini\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1089:16)
    at async C:\Users\Khaniini\project\index.js:15:3
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks! You are right it doesn't need cookies and curl would be most likely easiest way. Somehow curl with setcookies doesn't work with site that im using. It redirect site to login page.

I solved my problem with python pyautogui. It just manually click download button and save pdf-file :) I am still finding solution to download pdf-file with puppeteer